# Can an example be provided on how to stream an audio file with FMJ or JMF in Java

Tags: java, audio, stream, jmf, fmj

I have been looking for about 2 days for an example on how to do RTP streaming in FMJ or JMF that can be picked up through a browser or through a media program like VLC.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Download the source zip file from [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/). There is a file **SimpleVoiceTransmiter.java** in src.examples.rtp folder. You can use this source to stream audio file like wav.

Answer (score -1):

a bit late, but have you ever checked the jmf tutorial ? it is a real guide for you.
sometimes not sufficent, but shows you the right directions.

also, ever considered a free 3. party solution ?
just download MODERATOR-CONFERENCE from http://www.kemottron.com and give it a try.
it has some extra functions, such as, sms sending, chat, e-learning, live broadcast and file exchange. you may also setup its server side to achieve everything you need.

regards,